# Is it possible to geocode street intersections using Nominatim?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geocoding

Is it possible to geocode the location of a street intersection using Nominatim?

**Example geocode query**

```
Commonwealth Ave at Washington Street, Boston, MA
```

**Successful Geocode by Google**

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Commonwealth+Avenue+at+Washington+street,+Boston,+MA&hl=en&sll=42.351351,-71.118573&sspn=0.054868,0.132093&t=h&hnear=Commonwealth+Ave+%26+Washington+St,+Boston,+Suffolk,+Massachusetts+02135&z=17
```

**Failed Geocode by Nominatim**

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Commonwealth+Ave+at+Washington+Street%2C+Boston%2C+MA&viewbox=-337.5%2C85.34%2C337.5%2C-80.5
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: It's not yet implemented in version 2 of nominatim. Think it's going to be reviewed for next version.

Answer (score 1):

It should be able to. The [wiki page for Nominatim v2](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Version2#Search) says so:

> - Multilingual support for nearest / in / im (possible list of words in wiki (Name_finder:Translations) (in progress)
>     **- Searching for street intersections**
> - Provide option to use postgresql full text search module as alternative indexing method
> - Better formatting of address output (address format def on wiki? crowdsource?)
> - Indexing support for autocomplete text entry (prefix search)

Comment: How should I send the query to Nominatim? I tried `Street A at Street B` but that does not work.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but could you try `Street A corner Street B`?

Comment: Just tried, it does not work `http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Commonwealth+Ave+corner+Washington+Street%2C+Boston%2C+MA&viewbox=-337.5%2C85.34%2C337.5%2C-80.5`

Comment: The Wiki has it as a (TODO) item. I don't think this has been implemented yet, and there is also no mention of it on the MapQuest API which uses Nominatim.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to use geopy (python library). This library can use both google maps and nominatim geolocators. You can query both geolocators and compare them. If nominatim fails at junctions, you can pick Google for those entries.  Based on my experience Google Maps API is somewhat more forgiving on incomplete or more complex queries.

https://github.com/geopy/geopy