# A way to search street intersection on openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I need to find intersection by searching name of 2 streets; I found overpass API to query on osm data; the way I found was to find a node near a way; but the problem is all nodes don't have name and in most cases the answer isn't accurate, is there a better way?

Comment: There is a similar question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34075/is-it-possible-to-geocode-street-intersections-using-nominatim

Comment: not exactly, i'm sending query without nominatim, just overpass API http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#The_map_query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the following approach:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[highway][name="6th Avenue"];node(w)->.n1;
way[highway][name="West 23rd Street"];node(w)->.n2;
node.n1.n2;
out meta;
```

Try it on overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6Pb

Edit: `node.n1.n2;` calculates the intersection of input set .n1 and .n2. Please check the  [documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_input_set) for details.

Comment: Thank's that helped so much. but what does node.n1.n2 do? how can i see all possible answer and not just one?

Comment: It's the just intersection of all nodes in inputset .n1 and .n2. You will always get ALL possible answers in the area you specify: just remove the [bbox:{{bbox}}] in the first line to get 3 of those intersection worldwide (all of them in the US).

Comment: Thank you I did and yet I didn't get the correct intersection, I guess it's because of limitation of map data, Iran osm map isn't complete

Comment: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6Pf It just finds 2 node in Iran and of course not the one i mean

Comment: You could check if both ways are in your result: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6Pg

Also, it is important that both ways technically share at least one node. If they just intersect but don't have that common node, you would have to look into the `around` filter instead.

Comment: I need to use overpass-api server local, I found this link: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/install but it says "Additional functionality like management of areas and the line diagram utils aren't covered yet",what does that mean?Can't I use opverpass-api local and request query?

Comment: This is a completely different issue and not related to your original question.

Comment: A question on how to enhance this answer: How can you get the output to include the street names as well as city/country code?

Comment: @ErvinRuci : please ask a new question!

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me. Could be enhance.

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
(way[highway="motorway"];way[highway="trunk"];way[highway="primary"];way[highway="secondary"];way[highway="tertiary"];way[highway="unclassified"];way[highway="track"];way[highway="service"];way[highway="residential"];)->.n1;
foreach.n1(
    (.n1; - ._;)->.n2;
    node(w._)->.n3;
    node(w.n2)->.n2;
    node.n3.n2;
    out;
  );
```

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/bkD

It keeps crossing, if you don't need it, just substract the set of crossing to the intersection node (node.n3.n2).